# How to change the colors of these lines from Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, interface-design

I would like to change these colors of the lines in the red frame, from Adobe Illustrator. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the selection color of each layer

To change it:

- Double click on the layer to open the *Layer Options*
- Choose another color > OK
- Collapse and expand the layer group

[image]

Comment: What recording software you used?

Comment: –––––– Kap ––––––